# HIghcharts: How to create an area range chart with hard coded data?

Tags: highcharts

The Highcharts area range example uses data from json.  I'm not sure how to modify this example to include data hard coded in the JavaScript.

Here's the Highcharts demo chart I want to modify:

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/WRcj9/

Answer (score 0):

Store json return into a var.
Then you can change it's values, the first number is the date in utc, the second is the min and the third is the max.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WRcj9/46/)